# Is it possible write a partial in Ruby on Rails that work to different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is possible to create partials to be used inside forms that are semanticaly similar but have diferent attributes?

One example to explain the idea.

Imagine that we have the follow models:

```
class UnitedStatesTemperature < ApplicationRecord
  # higher_fahrenheit
  # lower_fahrenheit
end
```

and

```
class BrazilTemperature < ApplicationRecord
  # higher_celsius
  # lower_celsius
end
```

and the partial `shared/_temperatures.html.erb`

```
<%= form.label :higher_celsius, 'Higher' %>
<%= form.text_field :higher_celsius, id: 
:brazil_temperature_higher_celsius %>

<%= form.label :lower_celsius, 'Lower' %>
<%= form.text_field :lower_celsius, id: 
:brazil_temperature_lower_celsius %>
```

If we use this partial into a `brazil_temperature` form, it runs fine

```
<%= form_with(model: brazil_temperature, local: true) do |form| %>

  <%= render 'shared/temperatures', form: form %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If we use the same partial in the `united_states_temperature` it does not work (because attributes are differents).

My question is:

Is possible to rewrite the partial (`shared/_temperatures.html.erb`) in a generic way that it can be used in both forms (`brazil_temperature` and `united_states_temperature`)?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

You could make it more generic if you pass the form partial the attribute names.

```
<% underscored_klass = form.object.class.name.underscore %>
<% form_id = ->(attr) { "#{underscored_klass}_#{attr}".to_sym } %>

<% # use the two lines below only if you want certain default attributes %>
<% lower_temp_attr = lower_temp_attr || :lower_celsius %>
<% higher_temp_attr = higher_temp_attr || :higher_celsius %>

<%= form.label higher_temp_attr, 'Higher' %>
<%= form.text_field higher_temp_attr, id: form_id[higher_temp_attr] %>

<%= form.label lower_temp_attr, 'Lower' %>
<%= form.text_field lower_temp_attr, id: form_id[lower_temp_attr] %>
```

Then call the partial as follows:

```
<%= form_with(model: brazil_temperature, local: true) do |form| %>

  <%= render 'shared/temperatures', form: form, lower_temp_attr: :lower_celsius, higher_temp_attr: :higher_celsius %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I'm not mistaken the id gets automatically set to `model_name_attribute_name`. This means you could leave out the `<% form_id = ->(attr) { "#{underscored_klass}_#{attr}".to_sym } %>` and `id: form_id[higher_temp_attr]` parts to clean up the code a bit.

## Variations

The use of the variations is meant to clean up the view a bit. This way you don't have to pass `lower_temp_attr: :lower_celsius, higher_temp_attr: :higher_celsius` when rendering the partial for different variations of the form.

### Use a Helper

You could create a helper that returns the attribute name based on the object.

*app/helpers/temperature_helper.rb*

```
module TemperatureHelper

  def lower_temp_attr(temp) # variation #1
    attribute_names = temp.attribute_names

    return :lower_celsius if attribute_names.include?('lower_celsius')
    return :lower_fahrenheit if attribute_names.include?('lower_fahrenheit')

    raise ArgumentError,
          'Passed object should have either "lower_celsius" or ' +
          '"lower_fahrenheit" as attribute.'
  end

  def higher_temp_attr(temp) # variation #2
    attribute_names = temp.attribute_names
    options = %w[higher_celsius higher_fahrenheit]

    attr_name = attribute_names.find { |attr_name| options.include?(attr_name) }

    return attr_name.to_sym if attr_name

    raise ArgumentError,
          'Passed object should have either "lower_celsius" or ' +
          '"lower_fahrenheit" as attribute.'
  end

end
```

Then call `lower_temp_attr(form.object)` in your partial.

### Use the Model

Last but not least you could leave out the helper and make sure every temperature model responds to a certain interface method that returns the attribute name.

*app/models/generic_temperature.rb*

```
class GenericTemperature < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  def lower_temp_attr # variation #1
    return :lower_celsius if attribute_names.include?('lower_celsius')
    return :lower_fahrenheit if attribute_names.include?('lower_fahrenheit')
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def higher_temp_attr # variation #2
    options = %w[higher_celsius higher_fahrenheit]
    attr_name = attribute_names.find { |attr_name| options.include?(attr_name) }
    attr_name&.to_sym or raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

Than let your Temperature models inherit from *GenericTemperature*.

```
class UnitedStatesTemperature < GenericTemperature
end
```

And call `form.object.lower_temp_attr` in your partial.

There are many more ways to solve this issue. For example you could also choose to always raise the `NotImplementedError` exception in `GenericTemperature` and implement the method for every model. In this case inheriting from `GenericTemperature` does nothing except making sure that an `NotImplementedError` exception is raised if you didn't define the method in the model that inherits e.g. `UnitedStatesTemperature`.

If you're unable to inherit from a parent model for some reason (maybe you use it for something different) you can always place the code in a module and include it.

Answer (score 0):

First define a class method which returns scale of the temparature

```
class UnitedStatesTemperature < ApplicationRecord
  # higher_fahrenheit
  # lower_fahrenheit

  def self.scale
    :fahrenheit
  end
end


class BrazilTemperature < ApplicationRecord
  # higher_celsius
  # lower_celsius

  def self.scale
    :celsius
  end
end
```

Then write a partial like below `shared/temperatures`

```
<%
  higher_scale = "higher_#{form.object.class.scale}".to_sym
  lower_scale = "lower_#{form.object.class.scale}".to_sym
%>

<%= form.label higher_scale, 'Higher' %>
<%= form.text_field higher_scale, id: 
"#{form.object.class.table_name}_#{higher_scale}" %>

<%# same for lower --%>
```